# Continuous Function,Image, Domain,

Tags: calculus

I wonder if the image of an injective and continuous function is an open interval then your domain is also an open range ? (If the case is true, this is true for any type of function ? )

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question in the following way: If $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, injective and $f(D)$ is an open interval, does $D$ have to be open in $\mathbb{R}$?

The answer to this question is No.

For example, the map $f: (-2,-1) \cup \{0\} \cup (1,2) \to (-1,1)$ defined by $f(x) = x + 1$ if $x < 0$, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = x - 1$ for $x > 0$ is continuous and bjiective, but $(-2,-1) \cup \{0\} \cup (1,2)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.